# How do I use the "replace" function in XSLT 1.0 to remove special characters from my XML to get the correct JSON output?

Tags: json, xml, xslt

XML I was given

```
<root>
<page>0</page>
<totalRecords>74</totalRecords>
<totalPages>1</totalPages>
<offset>0</offset>
<status>success</status>
<entityList>
    <ENAME>
        <ADAMS>
  </ENAME>
        <DNAME>&RESEARCH</DNAME>
        <JOB>CLERK</JOB>
        <EMPNO>7876</EMPNO>
        <HIREDATE>1987-05-23 "00: 00 ":00.0</HIREDATE>
        <LOC>DALLAS</LOC>
    </entityList>
    <entityList>
        <ENAME>>ALLEN</ENAME>
        <DNAME>&SALES</DNAME>
        <JOB>SALESMAN</JOB>
        <EMPNO>7499</EMPNO>
        <HIREDATE>1981-02-20 00:00:00.0</HIREDATE>
        <LOC>CHICAGO</LOC>
    </entityList>
    <entityList>
        <ENAME>Abhi></ENAME>
        <DNAME>&SALES</DNAME>
        <JOB>PRU</JOB>
        <EMPNO>7956</EMPNO>
        <HIREDATE></HIREDATE>
        <LOC>CHIC"AGO "</LOC>
    </entityList>
</root>
```

MY XSLT block thus far

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
             <xsl:template match="root">
            {
             "page":<xsl:value-of select="//page"/>,
             "totalRecords":<xsl:value-of select="//totalRecords"/>,
             "totalPages":<xsl:value-of select="//totalPages"/>,
             "offset":<xsl:value-of select="//offset"/>,
             "status":"<xsl:value-of select="//status"/>",
             "entityList":[<xsl:for-each select="entityList"> 
             
        {
        "ENAME":"<xsl:value-of select="translate(ENAME,'&lt;,&gt;','')"/>",
        "DNAME":"<xsl:value-of select="replace(DNAME,'&amp;','')"/>",
        "JOB":"<xsl:value-of select="JOB"/>",
        "EMPNO":"<xsl:value-of select="EMPNO"/>",
        "HIREDATE":"<xsl:value-of select="replace(HIREDATE,'&quot;','')"/>",
        "LOC":"<xsl:value-of select="replace(LOC,'&quot;','')"/>"
        }
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">,</xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each> 
             ]
             }
             </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Do I use the replace function or do I use translate? On here I see people use variables but I am new to XSLT and am just learning everything.

I need to remove the '&', the '<>', and the quotes in the hire date along with all other special characters in the XML

Please assist with pointers and tips as you can. Thank you.

Comment: You need to **escape** the special characters (backslash, quote, tab and line break), not remove them. If you're using XSLT 1.0, you will need to use a recursive named template for this. The `replace()` function requires XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `replace()` function in XSLT 1.0; it was introduced in 2.0.

You can remove special characters using `translate()`, for example `translate(., '&amp;', '')`.

But what do you really want to do? Why are you trying to remove these characters? It looks as if you're trying to output JSON, in which case the way to handle these characters correctly is simply to use `<xsl:output method="text"/>`.

Comment: Using `<xsl:output method="text"/>` alone will not solve the problem of quotes contained in text nodes.